When one core interrupts another, how to guarantee read of the most recent value (stored before the interrupt) using stdatomic?
In a dual-core embedded system, core0 needs to interrupt core1 for several reasons. An enum paired with a union is used to pass both the reason and the data of the interrupt. The code is written in C.
#include <stdatomic.h>

typedef enum { // the interrupt reason, also indicates which member is valid in the union
  kData0,
  // ...
} InterruptId;

typedef struct {
  _Atomic InterruptId interruptId;
  union { // data associated with interruptId
    int data0;
    // ...
  };
} SharedMemory;

// core0
void InterruptCore1(); // write some registers in ARM GIC to interrupt core1
void PassData0ToCore1(SharedMemory *mem, int data0) {
  mem->data0 = data0;
  atomic_store_explicit(&mem->interruptId, kData0, memory_order_release);
  InterruptCore1();
}

// core1
void ProcessData0(int data0);
void OnCore0Interrupt(SharedMemory *mem) {
  InterruptId id =
      atomic_load_explicit(&mem->interruptId, memory_order_acquire);
  switch (id) {
  case kData0:
    ProcessData0(mem->data0);
    break;
  }
}

The above code seems to be incorrect, as core1 may see an outdated value of interruptId. As I understand it, the Release-Acquire ordering doesn't guarantee that load can read the most recent value. Maybe atomic_thread_fence is the solution here.
typedef struct {
  InterruptId interruptId;
  union {
    int data0;
    // ...
  };
} SharedMemory;

// core0
void InterruptCore1(); // write some registers in ARM GIC to interrupt core1
void PassData0ToCore1(SharedMemory *mem, int data0) {
  mem->data0 = data0;
  mem->interruptId = kData0;
  atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_release);
  InterruptCore1();
}

// core1
void ProcessData0(int data0);
void OnCore0Interrupt(SharedMemory *mem) {
  atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_acquire);
  InterruptId id = mem->interruptId;
  switch (id) {
  case kData0:
    ProcessData0(mem->data0);
    break;
  }
}

Both the release and acquire version of atomic_thread_fence compile to dmb ish, which seems to be correct in the machine level. But then I come to read the C++ version of atomic_thread_fence and find it also requires the use of atomic variables, and the synchronization only works if load actually reads the released value.
Does that mean the second solution has the same problem as the first (core1 may read an outdated value)? How to guarantee core1 can read the most recent value? Thanks very much.

Interesting.  With one core interrupting another, this is a rare case where it actually does make sense to talk about "the latest value" instead of just order (see Does atomic read guarantee reading of the latest value?).

@PeterCordes Why is this a special case? Looks like the same reasoning applies.

@n.m.couldbeanAI: Because no other writes are in flight from other threads.  We know a store happens before we trigger execution of a reader.  But loads do always take the latest value they can see, so if it's not seeing this store, the problem is that it didn't become visible yet so isn't "the latest value" of that variable from that core's PoV.  I ended up writing an answer where I think I see the problem in terms of ordering (between the store and the interrupt-sending code.)

(Correction to my previous comment.  We know a store is sequenced before the code that triggers execution of code on another core.  Apparently it's not a "happens-before" in the C++ sense because a load in interrupt handler doesn't see it.)

Interesting.  With one core interrupting another, this is a rare case where it might actually make sense to talk about "the latest value" instead of just order (see Does atomic read guarantee reading of the latest value?).  But on second thought, we can just talk about this in terms of ordering.
You want to create a happens-before relationship between the InterruptCore1(); in one core and the interrupt handler on the other core that's going to run OnCore0Interrupt.  Since inter-processor interrupts aren't memory operations (let alone part of std::atomic), you can't get what you want with std::atomic_thread_fence or other memory barriers.
I think the key is to wait until the store is globally visible (committed to cache) before interrupting the other core.  If you don't do that, no barrier on the read side can know it's supposed to wait for some specific store to appear. Barriers order operations in the same thread wrt. each other (by waiting for earlier ops to finish before allowing later ops).  This doesn't help when the store you're waiting for is still in flight (in a store buffer) on another core.
So you want a dsb ish or dsb sy on the writer core.
Possibly also a dmb ish?  I don't know ARM barriers that well, I just googled and found Real-life use cases of barriers (DSB, DMB, ISB) in ARM which summarizes with DSB - whenever a memory access needs to have completed before program execution progresses.)  Probably an ARM expert can post an answer (or edit this with a new section) about the details and if asm volatile("dsb sy" ::: "memory") after the store, before InterruptCore1() is sufficient on paper.
Using just ISO C/C++ std::atomic functions, you could have the reader spin-wait for some sequence number that you release-store in the writer, in a separate variable, but that sucks vs. having the writer use a different barrier to make sure the store is visible to loads in other cores.

and the synchronization only works if load actually reads the released value.

That's the same in C and C++, not a difference between them.

Thanks for the answer. dsb is more suitable here. But since InterruptCore1() is implemented by writing to memory-mapped registers, I think dmb should also work?

@Jackoo: Oh, in that case yes, dmb sy or maybe still dmb ish should work, in which case atomic_thread_fence right before InterruptCore1 should do it.  Possibly even with a memory order of release instead of seq_cst, although IIRC there isn't a weaker barrier.  I think 32-bit ARM does have just a StoreStore barrier (a different operand to dmb) so you might be able to use that via inline asm.  mo_release needs LoadStore + StoreStore so there's no C++ memory_order that can compile to it.


As I understand it, the Release-Acquire ordering doesn't guarantee that load can read the most recent value.

All memory orders guarantee that all threads see "the most recent" write to all atomic objects. The differences arise from what state you can see in other objects, i.e. whether writes to other objects can be re-ordered around the atomic reads or writes.

You can try to use some RMW operation to get the latest value from modification order. For example fetch_add(0). But you also need to store with RMW. For example exchange(...).

That's not what atomic RMWs actually guarantee.  See Is the order of a side effect in the modification order determined by when the side effect is produced? - they're guaranteed to read the last value in the mod order before the one they store, not "the latest value" in terms of freshness, which is normally not something that can be usefully defined.  The C++ standard doesn't talk about mod orders growing as the program runs, it's a view of the whole lifetime of the object.

If this works on ARM, it's because of a memory-barrier implementation detail of exchange on &mem->interruptId (especially with the default seq_cst memory order) making the store visible before the interrupt.  If that's the case, the reader doesn't need to be an RMW, like I explained in my answer.
